# Importing existing CloudFormation resources into CDK at scale

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, aws-cdk

Assume I have a very large number of existing CloudFormation stacks (many 1000s across multiple accounts). The in-house custom tooling that was used to create these stacks and resources is no longer maintainable and I want to move to CDK.

I want to bring these stacks and resources under CDK control. Is there an accepted best practice for doing this? The number of stacks means rewriting the stacks or manual resource by resource imports is not viable.

It feels like I’m possibly after a means of synthesising a high level language script from a CloudFormation template (basically the reverse of `cdk synth`). Any ideas on how I might achieve this? Are there other approaches I should consider?

Comment: Almost impossible to say what a good approach would be without actually knowing about how your existing stacks are made, what your tooling does, and how exactly you want to manage new and existing resources with the CDK. How many CFN templates do you have? Is it just a few templates with many stacks created by them with different parameters? Or do you have thousands of templates? Unfortunately, there is no magic bullet when it comes to existing stacks/resources... trying to generate CDK code is probably just going to amplify problems at this scale.

Answer (score 2):

#### Edit Feb 2024:  ✨ CDK codegen with `cdk migrate` ✨

AWS has [introduced](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2024/02/aws-cloudformation-templates-cdk-apps-minutes) the `cdk migrate` command, which can generate a CDK app from a deployed CloudFormation stack.  Here's an example that creates a new Python CDK app from the cloud-side `MyCloudFormationStack`:

```
cdk migrate --from-stack --stack-name "MyCloudFormationStack" --language python
```

You can also migrate deployed but unmanaged resources (`--from-scan`) and local templates (`--from-path`).

See the `migrate` [command reference](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/v2/guide/ref-cli-cdk-migrate.html) and the accompanying page [Migrate to AWS CDK](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/v2/guide/migrate.html) in the docs.

The command creates a new CDK app with a single stack.

---

#### Original Answer:

The [CfnInclude](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.cloudformation_include-readme.html) construct "imports" resources from an existing CloudFormation template file. The resulting CDK construct is a collection of [L1 resources](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/v2/guide/constructs.html#constructs_l1_using), corresponding 1:1 to the template resources.

```js
const cfnInclude = new CfnInclude(this, "Include", {
  templateFile: "path/to/template/file",
  parameters: {
    MyParameter: isA ? "valueA" : "valueB",
  },
});
```

You will want assurance that the resulting CDK stacks have recreated the existing templates with 100% fidelity. The CDK has your back with this, too:

- The CDK's [unit](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.assertions-readme.html) and [integration](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/integ-tests-alpha-readme.html) testing constructs have assertion and snapshotting tools.
- The CDK CLI can [diff](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/v2/guide/cli.html#cli-diff) CDK artefacts against the cloud-side CloudFormation templates. And the [--method=prepare-change-set](https://github.com/aws/aws-cdk/blob/main/packages/aws-cdk/README.md#cloudformation-change-sets-vs-direct-stack-updates) flag on `cdk deploy` will create a change set without executing it.